# elapsed time from database

Tags: php, mysql, elapsedtime

I am trying to create an elapsed time using date_purchased from a database table called order. I know I am getting the date_purchased as I can

```
<?php echo zen_datetime_short($order->info['date_purchased']); ?>
```

and get the date and time formatted as 04/20/2014 11:19:56
I'm not good with php and am just starting to learn this but from what I have researched I have tried the following

```
<?php
$first  = $order->info['date_purchased'];
$second = new DateTime( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$diff = $first->diff( $second );
?>
```

Then I do

```
<?php echo $diff->format( '%H:%I:%S' ); ?>
```

Unfortunately the page loads up until my echo and then everything that should appear below it doesn't.  I preferably would only want to show minutes and seconds on my output.

Thanks for your help. I'm using php 5.3 on my server.

Comment: I should add that the database is mysql just in case it matters and I'm using zen-cart.

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow. Enable [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php#85096) to get an error instead of *nothing* after this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     echo $dt."<br>";

     $difference = strtotime($dt) - strtotime("20-04-2014 20:14:30");

    // getting the difference in minutes
     $difference_in_hours = $difference / (60*60);

     echo $difference_in_hours."<br>";

    function sECONDS_TO_DHMS($seconds)
      {

         $days = floor($seconds/86400);
         $hrs = floor($seconds/3600);
         $mins = intval(($seconds / 60) % 60); 
         $sec = intval($seconds % 60);

            if($days>0){
              //echo $days;exit;
              $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
              $hours=$hrs-($days*24);
              $return_days = $days." Days ";
              $hrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
         }else{
          $return_days="";
          $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
         }

         $mins = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
         $sec = str_pad($sec,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

         return $return_days.$hrs.":".$mins.":".$sec;
      }
      echo sECONDS_TO_DHMS($difference);
```

replace the second time field with the datetime you are taking from the database.

Comment: This almost got me there!    $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     echo $dt."<br>";

     $difference = strtotime($dt) - strtotime($order->info['date_purchased']);

    // getting the difference in minutes
     $difference_in_minutes = $difference / 60;
     echo $difference_in_minutes." minutes";   I was able to out put into X.XXXX minutes   I would like to echo h:m:s format

Comment: Should I change  $difference_in_hours." hours"; with  echo $difference->format( '%H:%I:%S' );  Sorry but I cannot figure out how to put the code into the code wrappers

Comment: Mark answer if this was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with zen-cart but according to the documentation, [zen_datetime_short](http://www.sourcexref.com/xref/zencart/nav.html?admin/includes/functions/general.php.source.html#l170) appears to take a raw string as a parameter.

What (I think) this means is you are trying to use a string as a PHP `DateTime` object, which will cause your script to fail. You could try modifying your script to convert the raw timestamp from the database into a `DateTime` object as follows, and seeing if you have a better result:

```
$first  = new DateTime($order->info['date_purchased']);
$second = new DateTime();
$diff   = $first->diff($second);

echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S') . "\n";
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work.  Is there a way to convert a sting into an object?  I am finding many search results for object into a string but not string into object.  Perhaps there is a way to do an elapsed timer with a sting?

Comment: You can certainly create a `DateTime` object from a string, [here is the __construct documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). What format and what type is `$order->info['date_purchased']` (You could try `var_dump($order);` to see this information)? Do you have the error message to hand?